# Why is SQL truncating my data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, truncate

I am trying to insert data into a field defined as nvarchar(1000), using SSMS (SQL Server 2008). It will not allow me to enter a literal 1000 characters long. I get the message:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1 String or binary data would be
>   truncated. The statement has been terminated.

If I shorten it to 850 characters, it does the insert, but using LEN() reveals that it has truncated the data to just 749 characters.

I really need my 1000 characters. How can I load this data?

Here is my script:

```
    INSERT INTO [OnsiteV3].[dbo].[SQLPendingEvent]
       ([KeyDeviceID]
       ,[UpdateTime]
       ,[EventClass]
       ,[EventCode]
       ,[EventType]
       ,[EventDateTime]
       ,[KeyPropertyID]
       ,[KeyEntityID]
       ,[EventText]
       ,[KeyUserID]
       ,[EventImage]
       ,[TaskType]
       ,[TaskSubType]
       ,[UniqueTaskID])
 VALUES
       ('SVS-IMPL-DARREN'
       ,GETDATE()
       ,'REPAIR'
       ,'NOTE'
       ,'ADD'
       ,GETDATE()
       ,1003443
       ,10812
       ,'1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
       1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
       1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
       1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
       1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
       1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
       1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
       1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
       1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
       1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
       '
       ,'DARRENWORK'
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,'hsg00010812000P')
```

GO

Comment: Very interesting. Datalength gives a length of 1498! I guess it is counting line breaks and things.

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use a Text field?

Comment: @Tim "ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead." Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: @gvee thanks. Any reason you can't use varchar(max)? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is only due to formatting here on SO, but to me it looks like you are trying to insert about 80 characters of whitespace into the field as well, bringing your total character count up to 1080.

Also, `LEN` does not count trailing whitespace (yes, this is awful).

Answer (score 1):

*I  really need my 1000 characters. How can I load this data?*

One solution/workaround would be to remove the spaces, carriage returns and line feeds from the string:

```
replace(replace(replace( <your string> ', ' ', ''), char(10),''), char(13), '')
```

Applying this to your sample data (with blanks) makes it possible to insert into `nvarchar(1000)`.

If you want to keep the string as is, with blanks and`CR/LF`, the obvious solution would be to alter the table to allow longer strings, maybe to `nvarchar(max)`.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21263)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a user defined function for this purpose.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/10/sql-server-2008-enhenced-trim-function-remove-trailing-spaces-leading-spaces-white-space-tabs-carriage-returns-line-feeds/